# How to make a horizontal color scheme in android

Tags: android, listview, colors, color-scheme

I am using the google vision API and it can return the color scheme of a picture like this:

[image: google vision color scheme]

The API itself returns values to calculate the exact color from the RGB values and to calculate how much of the image contains that color in %.

I am trying to create something like in the first picture. But I have no clue how to do that, so far I just have a listview that gives an overview shown like here.

[image: listview overview]

Does anyone have an idea how I can create a horizontal color scheme in android where I specify all the colors myself? Even a horizontal listview might work with dynamic widths for each color to reflect the percentage.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `LinearLayout` and dinamically add child views to it with the `weight` equal to the percentage of the color :

```
// sample colors
final int color1 = Color.parseColor("#8da921");
final int color2 = Color.parseColor("#1f0929");
final int color3 = Color.parseColor("#f0b991");

// sample color percentages
final int colorPercentage1 = 60;
final int colorPercentage2= 10;
final int colorPercentage3 = 30;

// you should have this layout defined in your xml
final LinearLayout linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.linearLayout);
linearLayout.setWeightSum(100);

// create the views
final View view1 = new View(this);
final LinearLayout.LayoutParams viewParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
viewParams1.weight = colorPercentage1;
view1.setLayoutParams(viewParams1);
view1.setBackgroundColor(color1);

final View view2 = new View(this);
final LinearLayout.LayoutParams viewParams2 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
viewParams2.weight = colorPercentage2;  
view2.setLayoutParams(viewParams2);
view2.setBackgroundColor(color2);

final View view3 = new View(this);
final LinearLayout.LayoutParams viewParams3 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(0, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
viewParams3.weight = colorPercentage3;         
view3.setLayoutParams(viewParams3);
view3.setBackgroundColor(color3);

//finally add the views
linearLayout.addView(view1);
linearLayout.addView(view2);
linearLayout.addView(view3);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to make a horizontal color scheme in android

Simply inflate views with different weights inside of a LinearLayout with Horizontal orientation.